# Custom Dialog Presenter in Magnolia 5.0

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

In Magnolia 5.0 Dialogs are defined differently because Vaadin is used. Does anyone know how I can implement a custom Dialog Presenter for my Module ?

For example, I want to add a listener to a Textfield and update another field when the value changes. The Presenter should attach listener to the fields. I have seen an implementation of a Presenter but don't know where to tell the module that this one should be instead used of the default one.

In 4.5 you could add a class Property to the Dialog. So far I haven't seen anything like that in the documentation for 5.0 or the samples that come with the new version.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.field.builder.LinkFieldBuilder`. Builder defines a callback that updates the value of the text field after selection of link.

AFAIK it's not possible to set callback implementation just as a property of the dialog or of the field, but I might be wrong. You might want to ask on [Magnolia user forum](https://forum.magnolia-cms.com).

HTH,
Jan